# Join two List<T> with foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

I am attempting to move slightly away from LINQ which has proven very useful overall, but also quite difficult to read at times.

I used to use LINQ to perform joins (full outer join) but would prefer to do so using for/foreach loops for their simplicity. I just converted one LINQ statement (not PLINQ) into a nested foreach loop and the performance took a severe hit. What used to take seconds is now taking around a minute, see code below.

```
foreach (var p in PortfolioELT)
{
    double meanloss;
    double expvalue;
    double stddevc;
    double stddevi;
    bool matched = false;

    foreach (var a in AccountELT)
    {
        if (a.eventid == p.eventid)
        { DO SOME MATH HERE <-----
```

Any ideas on either

1. Why this is slower than LINQ Join and
2. How can I speed it up?

The program fairly obviously does what it needs to, but is too slow.

EDIT:
OLD CODE FULL

```
public static ConcurrentList<Event> CreateNewELTSUB(IList<Event> AccountELT, IList<Event> PortfolioELT)
    {
        if (AccountELT == null)
        {
            return (ConcurrentList<Event>)PortfolioELT;
        }
        else
        {
            //Subtract the Account ELT from the Portfolio ELT
            var newELT = from p in PortfolioELT
                         join a in AccountELT
                         on p.eventid equals a.eventid into g
                         from e in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             EventID = p.eventid,
                             Rate = p.rate,
                             meanloss = p.meanloss - (e == null ? 0d : e.meanloss),
                             expValue = p.expValue - (e == null ? 0d : e.expValue),
                             stddevc = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p.stddevc, 2) - (e == null ? 0d : Math.Pow(e.stddevc, 2))),
                             stddevi = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p.stddevi, 2) - (e == null ? 0d : Math.Pow(e.stddevi, 2)))
                         };


            ConcurrentList<Event> list = new ConcurrentList<Event>();
            foreach (var x in newELT)
            {
                list.Add(new Event(x.meanloss, x.EventID, x.expValue, x.Rate, x.stddevc, x.stddevi));
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
```

NEW CODE FULL:

```
    public static ConcurrentList<Event> CreateNewELTSUB(IList<Event> AccountELT, IList<Event> PortfolioELT)
    {
        if (AccountELT == null)
        {
            return (ConcurrentList<Event>)PortfolioELT;
        }
        else
        {
            //Subtract the Account ELT from the Portfolio ELT
            ConcurrentList<Event> newlist = new ConcurrentList<Event>();

            //Outer Join on Portfolio ELT
            foreach (var p in PortfolioELT)
            {
                double meanloss;
                double expvalue;
                double stddevc;
                double stddevi;
                bool matched = false;

                foreach (var a in AccountELT)
                {
                    if (a.eventid == p.eventid)
                    {
                        matched = true;
                        meanloss = p.meanloss - a.meanloss;
                        expvalue = p.expValue - a.expValue;
                        stddevc = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(p.stddevc, 2)) - (Math.Pow(a.stddevc, 2)));
                        stddevi = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(p.stddevi, 2)) - (Math.Pow(a.stddevi, 2)));
                        newlist.Add(new Event(meanloss, p.eventid, expvalue, p.rate, stddevc, stddevi));
                    }
                    else if (a.eventid != p.eventid)    //Outer Join on Account
                    {
                        newlist.Add(a);
                    }
                }
                if (!matched)
                {
                    newlist.Add(p);
                }
            }
            return newlist;
        }
```

Comment: please provide *complete concept* example...

Comment: If you convert it to LINQ that will improve the performance ;) Personally I'd put perf above readability. Then again I did start with assembler

Comment: Can you give an example of where your LINQ is difficult to read? I find that one of greatest strengths of LINQ is it's readability when structured properly. Are you using nothing but the method syntax?

Comment: How is this more readable than LINQ?

Comment: What was the LINQ equivalent?

Comment: Here's a great post by Jon Skeet about Join.  Notice the use of `ToLookup`.  http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-19-join.aspx

Comment: Can you post a working version? We can not help discover where the slowness is without seeing both the LINQ version and the foreach version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why this is slower than LINQ Join and

Im skipping answering this on purpose

> How can I speed it up?

You're looping over the entire `AccountELT` collection for every `PortfolioELT`. You should loop one, and have the other converted to a Dictionary to make finding a specifiec record easier. Something like:

```
var accountELTIdx = AccountELT.ToDictionary(k => k.eventid);
```

then

```
foreach (var p in PortfolioELT)
{
    double meanloss;
    double expvalue;
    double stddevc;
    double stddevi;
    bool matched = false;

    if(accountELTIdx.ContainsKey(p.eventid)
    {
        var acct = accountELTIdx[p.eventid];
        // some maths
    }
    ....
```

Comment: Excellent and simple answer. Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating local variables every iteration, that may or may not ever be used.

```
            double meanloss;
            double expvalue;
            double stddevc;
            double stddevi;
            bool matched = false;
```

You are doing a linear search for matching event id's, if just 1 of the Lists is ordered by "eventid" you could use binary search instead of the wasted effort of a full linear search.

```
            foreach (var a in AccountELT)
            {
                if (a.eventid == p.eventid)
```